# Reading excel file using jQuery/JavaScript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

Until now I was using epplus for excel file reading writing - standalone application.
Bt I've moved to web version, is it possible to read excel file or say 'to manipulate excel file **jQuery/JavaScript/AJAX**.

Comment: There are some js libraries to do it (like [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in similar fashion.

1. Upload an excel File
2. Read the uploaded file and return the data and bind a grid.
3. Allow the user to modifiy the data
4. Post the data back (or use ajax to post the data)
5. Write the new data in a new excel File and Download it.

You can use the same [EPPlus library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) or [NPOI library](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) to read/write.
Also you can use [Excel DataReader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com) to read the excel file.

Comment: that's for application specific...that would be same for web version?

Comment: Usually in the web version its prefered not to use any com component.
If your existing code is not using and com component you can reuse the same for web version.